# Redhat | Fuse | SSH file system

Tags: redhat, sshfs, fuse

I did manage setup and configure [fuse](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) and [sshfs][2] on my Redhat EL 5.4. But when I hit the sshfs it's out put an error

```
sshfs: error while loading shared libraries: libfuse.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

couldn't figure out the exact reason, requesting some helping hand

Thanks..

Comment: If the answer given was correct you should accept this as accepted answer. You can do this by clicking check before the answer.

Comment: sorry for my mistake..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install: fuse-libs:

e.g:

```
yum install fuse-libs
```

Check that you got the libs you need and that ldd finds your shared libs with:

```
ldd `which sshfs`
```